# array looped through foreach not displaying any data

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, foreach

I was working with an array which I have to list in a view page. so I iterated the array using a foreach loop. but it's not displaying any data and throwing an error like

`trying to get property of non-object`

I have tried the normal way but didn't get it

```
<div class="scrollbar1 table-content">
<?php
foreach($items_list as $row)
{
?>
<div class="table-row">
<div class="row list_row_style color_black common_rows">

<div class="col-md-12 no_padding">
<a href="add_ledger_sub_type?ledger_name=<?php echo $row->ledger_name; ? 
>">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2   list_common_text_style table-data">
<?php echo $i; ?></div>
<div class="col-md-3   list_common_text_style table-data" >
<?php if(!empty($row->sub_ledger_name)) echo $row->sub_ledger_name; ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3   list_common_text_style table-data" >
<?php if(!empty($row->ledger_name)) echo $row->ledger_name; ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4   list_common_text_style table-data" >
<?php if(!empty($row->description)) echo $row->description; ?>
</div>
</div></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</div>
```

My expected result is this code lists all items in '$items_list' array. But it's not

Please help me.

Comment: is it an array or an object?? should `$row->ledger_name` actually be `$row['ledger_name']`

Comment: both make the same effect. still no items displayed

Comment: and the wonder is other pages working properly with the same infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

can you put $row["ledger_name"] instead of $row->ledger_name

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I got the answer. It was a small mistake. I took the items to an array in `database_models` and again stored to another array in 'controller'.